# How to print out the contents of a HashMap in a certain format?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, iteration

I'm not entirely sure how I would do this, here is my code:

```
public class PizzaMenu
{
    static Map<String,Pizza> namedPizzas= new HashMap<String,Pizza>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }

    public static void addItem(String name, Pizza pizza)
    {
        namedPizzas.put(name, pizza);
    }

    public String printMenu()
    {
        /*
        String menuString="";
        for (Every menu item)

        {
            //Add name of menu item to menuString with carriage return
            //Add details of menu item (pizza.getInfo();) to menuString
        }
        */

        //return menuString
    }
}
```

I would then call `System.out.println(PizzaMenu.printMenu())` in another class. The sort of format I'm hoping to achieve is as follows:

```
/*
 * PizzaName
 *      Details
 * 
 * Next PizzaName in menu
 *      Details
 * 
 * Next PizzaName in menu
 *      Details
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
```

Am I maybe using the wrong data structure for this type of operation or is there a way of achieving this?

Here is the structure of the Pizza class (apologies for poor formatting):

```
public class Pizza
{
private double cost;
private Boolean veg;
private PizzaBase base;
private List<PizzaTopping> toppings = new ArrayList<PizzaTopping>();

public Pizza(PizzaBase base, PizzaTopping topping) //Constructor for pizza with 1 topping
{
    setBase (base);
    toppings.add(topping);
}

public Pizza(PizzaBase base, PizzaTopping topping, PizzaTopping topping2) //Constructor for pizza with 2 toppings
{
    setBase (base);
    toppings.add(topping);
    toppings.add(topping2);
}

public Pizza(PizzaBase base, PizzaTopping topping, PizzaTopping topping2, PizzaTopping topping3) //Constructor for pizza with 3 toppings
{
    setBase (base);
    toppings.add(topping);
    toppings.add(topping2);
    toppings.add(topping3);
}



public double getCost()
{
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(double cost)
{
    this.cost = cost;
}

public PizzaBase getBase()
{
    return base;
}

public void setBase(PizzaBase base)
{
    this.base = base;
}

public List<PizzaTopping> getToppings()
{
    return this.toppings;
}

public String getToppingsInfo()
{
    String toppingInfo = "\n";
    PizzaTopping t;
    for (int i = 0; i<getToppings().size();i++)
    {
        t = toppings.get(i);
        toppingInfo=toppingInfo+t.getInfo();
    }

    return toppingInfo;
}


public Boolean getVeg()
{
    return veg;
}

public void setVeg(Boolean veg)
{
    this.veg = veg;
}


public double calculateCost()
{
    PizzaTopping p;
    //Loop through all ingredients and add their costs to total cost
    for (int i = 0; i<toppings.size();i++)
    {
        p = toppings.get(i);
        cost+=p.getCost();
    }

    cost+=base.getCost(); //Add pizza base cost to total cost
    return cost;
}

//Check if pizza is vegetarian depending upon its ingredients 
public Boolean isVeg()
{
    Boolean toppingCheck =true;
    Boolean baseCheck = true;
    PizzaTopping t; //Temporary value used to stored toppings being compared in for loop

    //Check each topping and check if it's suitable for vegetarians
    for (int i =0; i<toppings.size();i++)
    {
        while (toppingCheck == true)
        {
            t = toppings.get(i);
            if (t.getVeg()==false)
            {
                toppingCheck = false;
            }
        }   
    }

    //Check base to see if it's suitable for vegetarians
    if (getBase().getVeg()==false)
    {
        baseCheck = false;
    }

    //Return value depending on if all ingredients are suitable for vegetarians
    if (toppingCheck == true && baseCheck == true)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else return false;

}

public String getInfo()
{
    String vegInfo;

    if (this.isVeg()==true)
    {
        vegInfo = "Yes";
    }

    else vegInfo ="No";

    return String.format("Toppings:%s\n"+"Base:\n%s"+"\nTotal Cost:\t£%.2f"+"\nSuitable for vegetarians: %s", getToppingsInfo(), getBase().getInfo(), calculateCost(), vegInfo);
    //Return list of toppings, Total Price, vegetarian

}
```

}

Comment: you just need to implement your printMenu(). Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: @EdgarBoda `for (Every menu item)` I suspect this part. @OP: try `HashMap.keySet().iterator()`

Comment: What's the structure of the Pizza class. Please include its code.

Comment: Also, use `toString()` for your method name. `printMenu` makes no sense as it doesn't print. Then your print statement will just be: `System.out.println(myPizzaMenu);`. `toString` will get called implicitly.

Comment: @EdgarBoda I'm not sure how obtain the keys from the map without explicitly knowing which keys are contained within it. For example, if I was using a list I could write namedPizzas.get(i) within the for loop to access each element in turn

Comment: @AJCol Read my comment. what you want is `keySet()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String menuString="";
for (Map.Entry<String, Pizza> pizzaItem : namedPizzas.entrySet()) {
    menuString += pizzaItem.getKey() + "\n";
    menuString += "\t" + pizzaItem.getValue().getInfo() + "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Sorry false alarm, this code doesn't seem to execute for some reason, the program just keeps running and doing nothing

Comment: @AJCol How do you call it?

Comment: First I tried to call it from another class, then I tried calling it within the main of PizzaMenu and then calling the main method from another class. After that, I tried calling it from the main method and simply running the main, all with no success

Comment: You added it to the printMenu() method? If you have your pizza in your map, this method will work guaranteed. The problem is somewhere else I think.

Comment: Yes, I ensured that printMenu() was called after all the pizzas were instantiated and added to the menu also

Answer (score 0):

```
public String printMenu()
    {

        String s ="";
        for (String key: namedPizzas.keySet()){
            s+= pizzaItem.getKey() + "\n";
            s+= "\t" + pizzaItem.getValue().getInfo() + "\n\n";               
        }
       return menuString
    }
```

Comment: `namedPizzas.get(key)` should just be `key`. `pizzaItem.getValue().getInfo()` should be `namedPizzas.get(key).getInfo()`

Answer (score 0):

To address your question directly:

You need a set of keys. With a set of keys you can also get values. [HashMap#keySet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) should work for this. You can loop through a set using a [for each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Then as you said, you need to build your string and return. Putting it together gives you:

```
public String printMenu()
{
    String menuString = "";
    for(String key : namedPizzas.keySet())
    {
        menuString += key + "\n" +
                      "\t" + namedPizzas.get(key).getInfo() + "\n\n";
    }
    return menuString;
}
```

I would also like to suggest a design improvement. You should be overriding the [Object#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method for things like this. The toString method will get automatically called when you try to print the object. This allows you to do: `System.out.println(myPizzaMenu);` instead of `System.out.println(myPizzaMenu.printMenu());`

The name printMenu is also misleading, so for that reason it's also bad.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, after switching the map to a list, it still didn't work. An hour later I found the bug causing it all! Thanks for everyone's answers, I will keep these methods in mind when I need to use maps again.

EDIT: Here is the new class structure for reference:

```
public class PizzaMenu
{
static List<Pizza> namedPizzas = new ArrayList<Pizza>();

public static void main(String[] args)
{

}

public static void addItem(String name, Pizza pizza)
{
    pizza.setName(name.toLowerCase());
    namedPizzas.add(pizza);
}


public static String  printMenu()
{
    String menuString="";
    Pizza p;

    //Collect all pizzas and add their information to string
    for (int i =0; i<namedPizzas.size(); i++)
    {
        p = namedPizzas.get(i);
        menuString+=p.getName().toUpperCase()+"\n"+p.getInfo()+"\n\n";
        p.resetCost();
    }

    return menuString;

}

}
```